# How to print / echo positional parameters index

Tags: scripting, parameter

I have this working and simple code to echo positional parameters VALUES

```
for i
do
echo "Argument = $i "
done
```

Here is the actual output from the scrip

```
Argument = --atleast-pkgconfig-version
Argument = 0.9.0
```

It does the job, but I have been trying to figure out how to ADD an index to the echo output.

This does not work

```
cnt=1
for i
do
echo "Argument $cnt = $i "
((cnt++))
done
```

The current code does the job, the index would be just icing on the cake - like this:

```
Argument #1 = --atleast-pkgconfig-version
Argument #2 = 0.9.0
```

Any ideas?

#### Update #1

I am posting this as a copy from text editor, basically to bypass „editing in 5 minutes „ time limit.

I did run both codes, both in #! /bin/sh scripts. One  is run directly in main script, the second is in script called from the main – as indicated. 
Both codes run fine in MAIN script, but the first code, the one I have originally posted as having an issue, does  not run in secondary script.

Yes, the “more portable” code solves the issue – it runs correctly in desired script. It still does not answer  the original question – why does it fail with “not found” error.

***MAIN script***

```
--exists glib-2.0                    0
--modversion glib-2.0                2.54.3
--exists --print-errors glib-2.0 >= 2.28    0
First code  - OK 
Argument #1 = dummy
Argument #2 = mt
Second code OK 
Argument #1 = dummy
Argument #2 = mt
```

***Secondary script***

First  code – FAILS

```
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-pkg-config: 19: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-pkg-config: cnt++: not found
Argument #1 = --print-errors
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-pkg-config: 19: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-pkg-config: cnt++: not found
Argument #1 = glib-2.0 >= 2.28
/usr/bin/a
```

***Second code – runs fine***

```
Argument #1 = --exists
Argument #2 = --print-errors
Argument #3 = glib-2.0 >= 2.28
```

***First code***

```
cnt=1
for i do
    echo "Argument #$cnt = $i"
    ((cnt++))
done
```

***Second code***

```
count=1
for arg do
    printf 'Argument #%d = %s\n' "$count" "$arg"
    count=$(( count + 1 ))
done
```

Comment: `j=0; for i do printf "arg#$((j=j+1)) = %s\n" "$i"; done`. And no, you cannot use `++j` in all shells.

Answer (score 2):

Your second example just needs an `#` in the output string to generate the correct output when run in `bash`:

```
cnt=1
for i do
    echo "Argument #$cnt = $i"
    ((cnt++))
done
```

Note that this would not generally work if executed with `/bin/sh`, especially not if `/bin/sh` is a shell (like `dash`) that does not understand the `((...))` syntax for arithmetic evaluation. The `dash` shell would generate a `cnt++: not found` error for the `((cnt++))` code above as it tries to execute the `cnt++` string inside two sets of sub-shells.  If you need to use the code above, make sure that it is executed by e.g. `bash` by using a `#!/bin/bash` line at the top of the script.

For maximum portability, you would use

```
count=1
for arg do
    printf 'Argument #%d = %s\n' "$count" "$arg"
    count=$(( count + 1 ))
done
```

This additionally avoids issues with arguments containing backslashes if the `xpg_echo` shell option happens to be enabled in `bash`, and it uses POSIX syntax for incrementing the counter.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work , at least in shell.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work , at least in shell. I believe the "cnt" is defined "outside" the "for" loop, hence "not found" in do /done code. Perhaps the "for" loop should be declared with  both i and  cnt as variables?  My guess would be that bash / shell do not have that option, I cannot get pass syntax error.

Comment: @anne Are you talking about the first piece of code in the answer specifically? That code would work in `bash` and I've tested it. If you execute the script with `/bin/sh` instead of `bash`, then it may well fail to work as expected (`/bin/sh` is not `bash` on many systems).  The second piece of code would work in any `sh`-shell (including `bash`). In both codes, the counter variable would need no special declaration inside the loop.